# Apply a Numerical value based on text from another cell

Tags: excel

I am quite a novice at excel an I am looking for some help.
I have an employment rota which my colleagues enter in their hours for their working week and it calculates the time worked for the week.

I am trying to allow the system to automatically assign a set time when the word "HOLS" (for holiday) is typed.  I want it to assign the value 07:15.

Is it possible to assign a rule that says;
 **IF the cell below ="HOLS" Then this cell should read "07:15"**

Regards

John

Answer (score 0):

If `HOLS` may be in say A2, then in A1:

```
=IF(A2="HOLS",7.25/24,"")
```

formatted to suit.